# Windows Batch: Handle errors with rundll32

Tags: batch-file, error-handling

I'm trying to remove a printer from the user's printer and devices. To make sure that I delete the printer, I have a series of `if` statements to remove a printer on the network or locally and to remove a printer via name or via name plus server connection.

My problem is that when I test the success of the printer being removed, the `errorlevel` always reports being `0` regardless of whether the printer was not successfully removed or not.

Does anyone know a way to handle errors with `rundll32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry`?

```
rundll32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /dn /n "%printerName%"
if %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 goto first else (goto after)

:first
rundll32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /dl /n "%printerName%"
if %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 goto second else (goto after)

:second
rundll32 printui.dll PrintUIEntry /dl /n \\DC1\%printerName%
if %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 goto third else (goto after)

:third
rundll32 printui.dll PrintUIEntry /dn /n \\DC1\%printerName%
goto after

:after
ECHO If printer was not deleted, click on the 'start' menu button, go to 'Devices and Printers', right click on the printer you want to remove, and select 'Remove Device'
```

Comment: rundll32 doesn't set ERRORLEVEL, because it has no idea what the process it is running has as a result. It's just running that process. See the [documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee649171.aspx) for rundll32. The process that it runs would have to return an ERRORLEVEL, and I don't see anything that says that PrintUI.DLL's PrintUIEntry does so.

Comment: Is there any reason not to use the `c:\windows\system32\prn*.vbs` files for printer administration?

Comment: @MCND Other than my lack of knowledge, no. Could one of these files be used to remove a printer, and could you direct me to some documentation using these files please?

Comment: See [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725868.aspx). On the left menu there are links to the rest of the commands

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So `rundll32` doesn't set an `errorlevel`, so rather than going through `if` statements to delete the correct printer, I just removed all printer connections with the code below. This code does no error handling, but it could if necessary.

```
cscript "C:\Windows\System32\Printing_Admin_Scripts\en-US\prnmngr.vbs" -xc
```

This batch script was meant to fix network printer's configuration anyways, so I didn't try to delete locally connected printers. Here's my whole script to remove and add network printers in case anyone wants a look.

```
@ECHO off

ECHO To solve your printer configuration problem, we will first remove the printers having the problem.
pause

REM remove all printer connections
cscript "C:\Windows\System32\Printing_Admin_Scripts\en-US\prnmngr.vbs" -xc
if %ERRORLEVEL% GTR 0 (ECHO If printer was not deleted, click on the 'start' menu button, go to 'Devices and Printers', right click on the printer you want to remove, and select 'Remove Device') else (goto end)

:end
ECHO Continue to printer installation?

pause

REM install printers
start \\DC1\LaserP2055
start \\DC1\LexmarkX544
ECHo The network printers LaserP2055 and LexmarkX544 have been installed
ECHO Would you like to exit the program?
pause
exit
```